# HTTP Put is not working for me in MVC 4 Web API. I keep getting a 404

Tags: rest, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

```
var assetimage_id = $(this).closest(".assetImageWrapper").attr("data-assetimage_id");

    var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ "Asset_ID": assetimage_id, "Description": $(this).val() });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Assets/UpdateDescription",
            type: "PUT",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataToSend,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            }
    });
```

And here is the method that it is supposed to hit.

```
 [HttpPut]
        public Asset UpdateDescription(int Asset_ID, string Description)
        {
            return new AssetsService().UpdateAssetDescription(Asset_ID, Description);
        }
```

What looks out of whack?  The method is setting in a Web API controller called Assets.  All other methods work fine from it (GETS, POSTS).  This is when I'm running it by hitting F5 in Visual Studio 2012, so no IIS configuration was changed.  the Api route is what the default route is.

And my web.config supports all verbs:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default, simple types like 'Asset_ID' above and also string 'Description' are binded from Uri. In you scenario you seem to sending the content in the body, so you would need to change your api signature accordingly. BTW, you also cannot have multiple FromBody parameters on your action.

For a complex model, you need a view model created to contain them:

Once created:

```
public class AssetEstimatedValueUpdate
    {
        public int Asset_ID { get; set; }
        public string EstimatedValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can pass it in and all works well.

```
[HttpPut]
        public Asset UpdateDescription(AssetDescriptionUpdate _AssetDescriptionUpdate)
        {
            return new AssetsService().UpdateAssetDescription(_AssetDescriptionUpdate.Asset_ID, _AssetDescriptionUpdate.Description);
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  What would be the alteration?

Comment: you would need a wrapper object, let's say a class called AssetInfo and AssetId and Desription would be properties on it. You would then modify your action signature to access one parameter AssetInfo. Since this is a complex type, by default, Web API reads content from body of the request and binds the data to the the properties.

Comment: Another solution is simply pass the your 'Asset_ID' and 'Description' in the URL since, as Kiran mentioned, these parameters are of simple type and are binded from Uri query string parameter by default (and not in the request body).  For example, the url for your ajax call would look like this:  "/api/Assets/UpdateDescription?AssetID=" + assetimage_id + "&Description=" + $(this).val(),

Comment: I wanted to stay semantic with the REST API and keep it a PUT if it was an update.  I tried earlier with GET and that worked fine as well.